# knowledge areas of SharePoint 2007 Developer & book that covers every single thing a developer needs to know

Tags: 2007, books

I am working on SharePoint 2007 for last 9 months by working on tasks given by management, everyday I come across new things or more like discover new things, can anyone recommend me a book that will cover every single thing in SharePoint 2007 (MOSS) as I think 9 months is a long period and I still don't know everything about SharePoint 2007 and its such a embarrassment.

or

If there any series of videos all in one, teaching everything about Moss 2007 :)

Comment: I've been doing SharePoint for 7 years and still don't know every single thing in SP. :)

Comment: I cant imagine what size a volume like that would be.  SharePoint is not a "single" product but a conglomorate of existing products and technologies, with some new twists thrown in.  If you need a one stop shop, MSDN is the only place you will get close (even then it is not all inclusive).

Comment: The only thing you know is that you don't know everything. Can be hard to explain to customer sometimes, when they expect you to be a **S** u **P** er hero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a very short time working with SharePoint you will come across issues and quirks that will never be covered in any book.  SharePoint is a massive product and can be used for a bewildering number of very different uses.

The best ways to learn about SharePoint are:

- Get experience and make mistakes. Having your own dev environment that you are free to mess up and restore is a critical part of this;
- Learn to navigate the MSDN library and forums such as this one;
- Find a user group or a group of colleagues with experience in areas you want to know more about;

Being a SharePoint dev will tax your investigative and problem solving abilities to the fullest.  That may be part of the reason why there's so few of us around.

Good luck!

Comment: also - get really good at formulating google queries - that will help as much as anything

Comment: you forget to mention that you will become an expert of reverse engineering. Reflector, Just Decompile or ILSpy is, unfortunately, a must have tool in the SP developer's toolbelt. There are number of problems that can be solved by finding the correct, undocumented, hidden class. The best example I can name is the WorkflowAssociationPage. When you read the documentation, there is a bunch of tweaks to apply (hidden fields to add, etc.) in your custom page. But, if you look carefully, you will find a base class that handle of this, that you just have to inherits and put your logic.

Comment: yep, lots of tools will come into play.  F12 developer tools and Fiddler to name a couple more.  But there's an awful lot you can do in SharePoint without ever writing C# or debugging http or inspecting the DOM, so the tools really depend on what slice of SharePoint you're into at any given time

Comment: Now you guys made me more frustrated then ever :D LOL

Comment: maybe completing this [wiki answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40378/what-are-the-musts-have-tools-when-working-with-sharepoint/40379#40379) may help newcomers ?

Comment: Sorry, but its true.  SharePoint is like a giant toolbox where the same tool can be used for a dozen different things ... and to do other things, you need to make your own tools using the tools already available.  There is simply no way one single human being can understand it all to any great depth.  You either know one part really, really well or you know lots of it kinda well ... or you are in marketing and think you know it all really well but can only code via PowerPoint slides :)

Comment: @TimeToThine:  sorry, that wasn't my intention:) - but SharePoint solutions are not often linear like that - quite frequently my clients have requirements and considerations that are truly unique and can't be met using predefined procedures.

Comment: @Steve B:  I worry that a comprehensive list of tools would intimidate rather than help a novice developer.  Learn the basics first, then worry about the subset of tools that would help with the specific problems you are trying to solve.

Comment: the goal is not to intimidate, but to warn that this won't be an easy way.