# What are the must have tools when working with SharePoint?

Tags: development, administration, tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of SharePoint 2007 / WSS 3.0 development tools](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81/list-of-sharepoint-2007-wss-3-0-development-tools)

When developing or administering SharePoint, what are the must have tools?

*This question is intended to reference the most useful tools for any developer. It's a community Wiki, do not hesitate to contribute*