# Beginner Sharepoint 2010 advice

Tags: books

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An introduction to SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/an-introduction-to-sharepoint-2010)

Could you recommend me tutorials, books or websites on Sharepoint 2010 for a beginner level? I am an intern and my mission is collaborative site support, I'd like to start with that, and then broaden my knowledge in time. Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is related : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40371/knowledge-areas-of-sharepoint-2007-developer-book-that-covers-every-single-thi/40375#comment37067_40375 (not exact duplicate thought)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft) too. This is a great site but you must pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally started at [lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-training-tutorials/306-0.html). It does require a paid subscription I think its well worth it. You can also check out the [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428287.aspx) pages and the technet forums. Thats where I started :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Wrox book range](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-400599.html?query=sharepoint%202010&filter=books), they have some pretty good books on the subject. And for beginners, it's a good thing to find out what you want to begin with. Knowing all SharePoint components by heart requires a lot of studying.